# react child component not updates after set state in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, rerender

I have parent and child component and doing delete action in child component and then setting state in parent component but child component not showing new data before page reload.

Parent component:

```
  const { organizationId } = useParams();
  const [organizationData, setOrganizationData] = useState({
    projects: [],
  });
  const ctx = useContext(DashboardContext);


  const fetchOrganizationData = useCallback(async () => {
      const response = await // API ROUTE HERE
      setOrganizationData(response.data); // SET STATE HERE
  }, [organizationId, cookies.access_token, ctx.user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies.access_token) {
      jwt_decode(cookies.access_token);
      fetchOrganizationData();
    }
  }, [cookies.access_token, fetchOrganizationData, organizationId]);

 return (
    <>
          <OrganizationOverview
            organizationId={organizationId}
            organizationData={organizationData}
            fetchOrganizationData={fetchOrganizationData}
          />
       </> )
      }
```

OrganizationOverview component:

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
const ctx = useContext(DashboardContext);

const deleteMember = async () => {
      const response = await // API CALL HERE
      props.fetchOrganizationData(); // CALL FUNCTION IN PARENT COMPONENT WHICH SETS STATE
  
  
  };

return (  <MembersTable
                        members={props.organizationData.members}
                        deleteMember={deleteMember}
                      /> )
```

after clicking delete button in MembersTable component, member is deleted in database but it does not appear in front end before page reload

Comment: What happens if you remove `fetchOrganizationData` from your `useEffect` dependencies array? I mean, leaving only `[cookies.access_token, organizationId]`?

Comment: nothing changed, still same

Comment: can you write the API route url, you can replace your server name with `xyz`, I just need to see what params the URL need

Comment: const response = await getApi(ctx.cookies.access_token).post(
        'v1/organization/members/remove',
        {
          organization_id: organizationId,
          user_id: userId,
        }
      );

Comment: and when you delete a member(while opening the network panel on the right) do you see a new Get request to organization?

Comment: yes, with your answer I just realised I have problem with testing, I am deleting myself as member then it tries to fetch data but I do not have permission because I am no longer a member so it does not update state instead it goes in js catch block (which I deleted for code visibility here), thank you so much :)